# assigning data from df to a list with a loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

im new to python and need your help.
basically im having a list of strings and a dataframe called df which has many columns and rows, and im trying to assign each language to a seperate df based on a condition.
it looks like:

```
languages = ['JavaScript', 'HTML/CSS', 'SQL', 'Python', 'Bash/Shell/PowerShell', 'Java']

for language in languages:
   language = df[df['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.contains('language')]
```

I want each language to be assigned to a dataframe based on the condition, instead of assigning every language seperately like:

Python = df[df['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.contains('Python')]

C++ = df[df['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.contains('C++')]
etc...

how do i run the loop so each word in languages assign to a dataframe based on it's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary of DataFrames:

```
out = {}
for language in languages:
   out[language] = df[df['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.contains(language)]
```

Or in dictionary comprehension:

```
out = {language: df[df['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.contains(language)] 
                            for language in languages}
```

And then you can select each Dataframe by key:

```
print (out['Python'])
```

Comment: hey jezrael, i keep getting this error:
error: multiple repeat at position 2
do you know why it doesnt work?

Comment: fount the problem! there was some items on the list which had an operator like HTML/CSS so you cannot assign to those variables..once i fixed it it's fine, thanks!!